# $.get() jquery not update in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a  that when clicking on it - it send to js func. The func is jquery that get a text from a webpage (the webpage get thetext from sql). The problem is that in IE it is not work - the text from the webpage does not update. But the strange thing is that sometimes it updates and sometimes not.

Here is the `<a>` that call to the func:

```
<a href="##" title="" class="FeaturedButton" onclick="MakeFeatured(#itemid#); return false;">
<span class="make" >
Make featured item
</span>
</a>
```

Here the js func:

```
function MakeFeatured(itemid)
{
$.get('../../pa_listings/make_featured.cfm?itemid=' + itemid,function(data){
if (data.indexOf('ok') > 1) {
    alert('OK');
    $('#tr'+ itemid).remove();
}
else 
    alert('No manual ad slots left!');  
}); 
}
```

P.S. the problem just in IE browser, I check in all the other, so I think the problem is in the js not in my webpage text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to turn caching off, try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../pa_listings/make_featured.cfm?itemid=' + itemid,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.indexOf('ok') > 1) {
            alert('OK');
            $('#tr'+ itemid).remove();
        }
        else 
            alert('No manual ad slots left!');  
        } 
    }
});
```